# How can I use conditional logic to choose which record to join in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, if-statement, exists

I am working on a query that, among other things, selects one phone number for a person given their ID number.

This bit of code gets it:

```
LEFT JOIN [thedatabasename].dbo.[thetablename] Phone 
ON p.PersonId = phone.PersonId 
AND (phone.[Description] = 'Home Phone' 
     OR phone.[Description] = 'Cell Phone' 
     OR phone.[Description] is null)
```

This works, but what I want is for it do something that is conceptually more like

```
IF EXISTS select [phone number] from <tablename> where description = 'Home phone'
ELSE IF EXISTS select [phone number] from <tablename> where description = 'cell phone'
ELSE IF EXISTS select [phone number] from <tablename> where description is null
```

so that it prefers the 'home phone' over 'cell phone', and prefers 'cell phone' over one with no description. I don't know how to do that in the middle of my join though. Is there a way to do that without having to write three separate selects? The query that this join is part of is ugly and massive and has a bunch of joins, so separating it out would be tough. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use a CASE statement in the select?  Seems like you'd have more control.  You are already joining to the phone table. For reference: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/in-t-sql-use-casewhen-in-place-of-ifthen/5078041

Comment: just to clarify: when you say prefer home phone, you don't want to output cell phone record if you have 2 records: one with  a cell phone and one home phone  and your problem is that LEFT JOIN output both. right ?

Comment: Right. If they have a 'home phone' I want to get just that one, if not then I want just their 'cell phone,' if not I want a phone number with a NULL description. Most everybody has multiple entries in the phone number table, but with quite varied types. 
I think with what I have now it's just picking at random either their home, cell, or a NULL phone number.

Answer (score 3):

Because the three phone numbers are in different rows, you need three joins. Use a `case` statement to select the first one that is not null:

```
select
    ...
    case 
        when phone1.[phone number] is not null then phone1.[phone number]
        when phone2.[phone number] is not null then phone2.[phone number]
        else phone3.[phone number] 
    end as [phone number]            
    ...
LEFT JOIN [thedatabasename].dbo.[thetablename] phone1
    ON p.PersonId = phone1.PersonId AND phone1.[Description] = 'Home Phone'
LEFT JOIN [thedatabasename].dbo.[thetablename] phone2
    ON p.PersonId = phone2.PersonId AND phone2.[Description] = 'Cell Phone'
LEFT JOIN [thedatabasename].dbo.[thetablename] phone3
    ON p.PersonId = phone3.PersonId AND phone3.[Description] is null
```

Note the different aliases given to the joined `Phone` rows to distinguish them.

If your database supports `COALESCE` (or similar), you can simplify your select to:

```
select
    ...
    coalesce (phone1.[phone number], phone2.[phone number], phone3.[phone number]) as [phone number]            
    ...
```

Comment: instead of the CASE, why not use COALESCE(phone1.[phone number], phone2.[phone number], phone3.[phone number]) ?

Comment: @sybkar I would do that if coding it myself, but the question doesn't say which database is being used and not all databases support `COALESCE`. I'll add that as an alternative. Cheers

Comment: my apologies, I thought that was part of the SQL standard.  My mistake :)

Comment: @sybkar for example mysql implements the concept with its `ifnull(a, b, c, ...)` function

Comment: @Bohemain, actually, from my understanding, MySQL using COALESCE too, and uses ifnull() for a slightly different purpose (MS-SQL isnull())

Comment: It's T-SQL, COALESCE is supported. Sorry, I'm new to this and didn't know that info would help.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to assign a rank to each phone type in a subquery and select only the first.
this can be done with an analytic function or a suquery (select count(*) etc) , it depends on you server type.
mysql does not support analytic functions and it could look a bit weird but should work :-).
With MSSQL it gives :

```
select * 
from (
    select rank() over ( 
            partition by Person.PersonId
            order by 
                case when Phone.PhoneDescription = 'Home' then 1
                when Phone.PhoneDescription = 'Cell' then 2
                else 3 end  ) as [rank],
        Person.name, Phone.PhoneDescription, Phone.PhoneNumber
    from Person
    left join Phone on Person.PersonId = Phone.PersonId
) PhoneNumbers
where [rank] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @Bohemian's suggestion. If you are going to need this functionality often in multiple queries, you may want to write a table-valued function (if you db has such things) or view to calculate the correct phone number to present.  Then all refernces to phone number will always get the same number.

An alternative is to mark one and only phone number as the main one with a flag field (call it contactphone) and keep this updated through triggers. This is useful if the person to be contacted may specify which one he would prefer to be contacted through.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the privilege to create stored functions, I would replace that part of the query with a function call. The logic to decide which phone number to return can be written in this function. This keeps the main query clean and the function can be re-used in other queries as well.

MySQL function stub would look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `getPhoneNumber`(_PersonId INT) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
    // You SQL query here 
END
```

Comment: hm, that does seem like it would be simple. Or maybe I could create a view. Thanks!

Comment: Not a view since views cannot return a value. You could always create a view and join it with the main sql query but that is more cumbersome than just using a function call. I would still go with a function unless you have a strong reason not to, and in your requirement, I cannot find such a reason.